Failed to initialize reCAPTCHA config: No Recaptcha Enterprise siteKey configured for tenant/project
I writing a chat app and face with trouble with the OTP Authenticate with Firebase on Android using a Phone Number
whenever I write a real phone number there is a error and it dosent work
and shows me this errors:
Failed to initialize reCAPTCHA config: No Recaptcha Enterprise siteKey configured for tenant/project
[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 Invalid app info in play_integrity_token
here is the code:
String phoneNumber;
Long timeoutSeconds = 30L;
String verificationCode; // for verify the otp
PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken resendingToken; //for resending the otp to the user
EditText otpInput;
Button nextBtn;
ProgressBar progressBar;
TextView resendOtpTextView;
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_otp);

    otpInput = findViewById(R.id.login_otp);
    nextBtn= findViewById(R.id.login_next_btn);
    progressBar= findViewById(R.id.login_progressbar);
    resendOtpTextView = findViewById(R.id.resend_otp_textview);


    // getting the data from another Activity ( phone number --> "LoginOtpActivity")
    phoneNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phone");

    //starting otp send method with phoneNumber for the first time--> isResend=false
    sendOtp(phoneNumber, false); // method

    //verifying the OTP code when pressing "NEXT" button
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String enteredOtp = otpInput.getText().toString();
            PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationCode,enteredOtp);
            signIn(credential); // method
            setInProgress(true);
        }
    });

    // resending Otp code when pressing "Resend OTP code" textView
    resendOtpTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendOtp(phoneNumber,true); //method

        }
    });




}

//Send the otp METHOD
void  sendOtp (String phoneNumber, boolean isResend){
    startResendTimer();//method
    setInProgress(true); // set progressBar visible
    PhoneAuthOptions.Builder builder =
            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .setTimeout(timeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .setActivity(this)
                    .setCallbacks(new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        // When otp is automatically entered --> move to username
                        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                            signIn(phoneAuthCredential);
                            setInProgress(false);// set progressBar gone

                        }

                        @Override
                        //when something went wrong
                        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                            AndroidUtils.showToast(getApplicationContext(),"OTP verification failed");
                            setInProgress(false);// set progressBar gone

                        }

                        @Override
                        // this will send the otp to the user
                        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                            verificationCode = s;
                            resendingToken = forceResendingToken;
                            AndroidUtils.showToast(getApplicationContext(), "OTP sent successfully");
                            setInProgress(false);// set progressBar gone
                        }
                    });
    if (isResend){
        //verifying with resendingToken
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(builder.setForceResendingToken(resendingToken).build());
    }else {
        //verify the phone number
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(builder.build());
    }


}




//set the progressBar/nextBtn to VISIBLE/GONE METHOD
void  setInProgress(boolean inProgress){
    if (inProgress){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}



// login with Firebase and go to next activity METHOD
void signIn(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
    setInProgress(true);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                setInProgress(false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginOtpActivity.this, LoginUsernameActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("phone", phoneNumber);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                AndroidUtils.showToast(getApplicationContext(), "OTP verification failed");
            }
        }
    });
}



// Timer for resending OTP METHOD
void startResendTimer(){
    resendOtpTextView.setEnabled(false);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeoutSeconds--;
            resendOtpTextView.setText("Resend OTP in " + timeoutSeconds+" seconds");
            if (timeoutSeconds<=0){
                timeoutSeconds=30L;
                timer.cancel();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        resendOtpTextView.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    },0,1000);
}

tried to check my settings gradle and couldnt fine the problem...
